# Проверка аргументов Python

Tags: python

Нужно ли проверять аргументы функции?

```py
def divide(a: int, b: int) -> float:
    try:
        return a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0.0
```

Или

```py
def divide(a: int, b: int) -> float:
    return a / b
```

Comment: неправильный вопрос. Зависит от того, что хотите. Я бы вообще сделал `def divide(a, b)` и  `return a / b` :-) Просто 0 не надо передавать.

Comment: @Сергей если есть возможность передать ноль, кто-нибудь этим обязательно воспользуется. Исключение `ZeroDivisionError` придумано и используется не просто так

Comment: @Dmitry, в массе учебных примеров прямо пишут, что данные будут корректными, чтобы проверки не делали. А тут пример явно учебный. Так что всё же зависит от того, что хотим.

Answer (score 3):

Универсального ответа на этот вопрос нет. Но общее правило гласит -  "если пользователь имеет возможность ввести некорректные данные -  он их рано или поздно обязательно введет". Поэтому в серьезных программах проверка как входных данных так и всевозможных исключительных ситуаций может занимать процентов 80 а то и больше  всего объема написанного кода. А в учебных скриптах -  ну можно и не проверять.

Comment: А ссылку дадите на источник данных, что проверки занимают 80%+? :-)

Comment: Практический опыт. Как личный, так и очень многих коллег. Накопленный за 35+ лет практического программирования.

Comment: Давно не читал теорию, но по Бруксу-младшему было 65%.

Comment: Читал, помню. Будем считать, что ему везло. :-) Вот просто посмотрите пример в этом вопросе. И посмотрите, сколько надо было бы в него добавить проверок, если бы этот код использовался бы в действительно серьезных задачах -  от управления медицинскими приборами, до мониторинга работы АЭС.

Answer (score 2):

```py
except ZeroDivisionError:
    return 0.0
```

Молча "проглатывать" исключения - самый плохой вариант. Если уж ловите исключение, то нужно хотя бы этот факт как-то логировать:

```py
except ZeroDivisionError:
    logging.warning('Случилось деление на ноль!')
    return 0.0
```

Ну и в целом такой шаблон поведения хорош только его "ленивостью". Если вы точно хотите именно такого поведения функции, то лучше явно проверить случай `b == 0` прямо через `if`, чтобы тот, кто читал код, лучше понимал, что в нём происходит. Хотя в целом это всё-равно вопрос вкуса, конечно. Я бы, наверное, где-то выше по стеку такое исключение ловил. Всё-таки деление - это деление и оно должно быть предсказуемым. На ноль делить нельзя.

Например, вы можете вычислять среднее значение и выводить его куда-то, тогда лучше будет выглядеть наверное так:

```py
from typing import List, Union

def divide(a: int, b: int) -> float:
    return a / b

def get_mean(arr: List) ->  Union[float, str]:
    return divide(sum(arr), len(arr)) if arr else 'недоступно'

print(get_mean([1, 2, 3]))
print(get_mean([]))
```

Вывод:

```
2.0
недоступно
```

Comment: В целом соглашусь с написанным. Однако со сравнением float чисел -  я бы рекомендовал бы быть осторожнее. Известный пример : s = str('0.0')
f1=s
f1==0.0   Угадаете, что выдаст? Правильно, False. А не True, как хотелось бы. Это несколько смущает, особенно новичков.